# Selecting features based on specific attribute in d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, leaflet

I have a map: d3 vectors (circles) placed over a leaflet map.

```
    // read in data, draw circles in d3, and append to Leaflet map
    var feature = mapG.selectAll("circle")
        .data(SFData)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return type(d.properties.Tenant)})
        .attr("r", function(d) { return radius(d.properties.Lease_Size)})
        .attr("class", 'features')
```

I have a time filter, which makes certain features invisible if I don't want them visible on the map (code not shown here).  The way I do this is by setting those features' opacity to zero.

The issue is that I want popups to show up for only visible map features on mouse-over.  Currently the features which have opacity set to zero still can still be activated by mouse-over which is screwing things up.  So, I want to select only features which currently have opacity set to .7 (a time slider will dynamically change the opacity).

This doesn't seem to work:

```
// select d3 features of the class 'features', that have attribute opacity = .7
d3.selectAll('.features[style = "opacity: .7;"]')       
        .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
         console.log(" do something here")
        })
```

I've also tried to add a "classed" attribute, and select based on that.  While I can get the classed attribute to update successfully, nothing happens with mouseover.

```
 //build function to change attribute 'classed'
function ClassMatch(data, value) {    
    
     if (year <= inputValue) {          
     return "Visible";
    } else {
        return "invisible";
    };
}

// pass in a function which assigns 'classed' attribute based on function
var feature = mapG.selectAll("circle")
        .data(SFData)
        .enter().append("circle")        
        .attr("classed", ClassMatch)
        
// select on classed attr
d3.selectAll('.Visible')
```

What can I try next?

Comment: add a class to the visible items `.classed('visible', d=> { ...some logic...})` and use a `d3.selectAll('.visible')`, remove the class if you want them invisible, also remove the `mouseover` handler

Comment: rio - thanks!  I actually tried this exact thing earlier, with no success.  The method i used is outlined above.  Nothing happens on mouseover in this case, even though the classed attribute successfully is being updated and I can verify only the visible points are classed 'visible'.

Comment: you need to use the `classed()` method, and you don't use any of the data or value in your function, you do nothing with the `d3.selectAll('.Visible')`

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Comment: No. I'm able to add a class to visible items, by using classed() method.  I successfully got the visible items to be classed "visible" and invisible items to be classed "invisible".  Yet, this still selects all features:
                          d3.selectAll(".features")
      .classed("visible", true)
     .on("mouseover", function(d) {                                      
                                            console.log("visible item")                                        
                                           })

Comment: I just figured this out.  I was able to get this to work by writing a pointer-events function that would either return "all" or "none", which would then be passed into .attr("pointer-events").  It's working is it should now!  Thanks for the help, all.